# Modify message sent by rabbitMQ inside consumer

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

*Note:* Using [RabbitMq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) via [RabbitMQBundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/rabbitmqbundle) in [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/).

My producer sends a message like this :

```php
$message = array(
    'class' => get_class($receiver),
    'id' => $receiver->getId(),
    'stepNumber' => 1,
    'errorCount' => 0
);
```

The consumer retrieves the `$receiver` from the database and sends him an email.

```php
public function execute(AMQPMessage $msg)
{
    //Step1 - retrieve user from db

    //Step2 - send email

    //Step3 - update stuff in database
}
```

To keep track of the errors, I want to handle the exceptions at each step. If there is an exception thrown at step 3, I want to modify `stepNumber` to 3, increase the `errorCount` by 1 in `$msg`, and finally requeue the `$msg` by returning `false`.

This has the following advantages:

- When the consumer will process the message again, it will not send the email again.
- When the `errorCount > 5`, I just discard the message.. `return false`.

This would be great, but :

### Is there a way to modify the `$msg` before it is requeued by RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6399894/1721056) answer points out, RabbitMQ doesn't let you change messages after publishing them.  When you return false, RabbitMQ just puts the original message back in the queue for processing.

It is possible to get the same effect by republishing the message with the changes you want, then consuming the original message by returning true.  You will probably want to republish the message using the [default (nameless) exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html) so that you can send it directly to the queue that you got the original message from.

Comment: You mean, send a clone of the original message back to the queue instead of modify it?