# Cancelling an un-acked message in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a service which tasks worker processes via RabbitMQ. The messages are sent with a TTL, and the worker will not ack the message until it successfully completes the task sent in the message.

The tasking process will monitor workers for timeouts, and if a worker exceeds the timeout it will be terminated. Since the message isn't ack'd, the message is re-queued immediately and the next worker will pick up the message (this is useful in my scenario, as workers are unreliable and may fail but subsequent attempts typically succeed.

However, I would also like the ability to cancel a message. Terminating and re-creating the worker process is the normal procedure (it's single threaded, so I can't send a separate 'cancel' message to the worker). However, doing so leads to the message immediately re-queueing if the TTL has not been exceeded.

The only suggested solution I've found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758576/how-to-retract-a-message-in-rabbitmq), which suggested a separate data source which checks if a message is still valid. However, that answer is both a) old and b) inconvenient.

Does RabbitMQ offer a means to cancel a message once it's been placed into the queue?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately rabbitmq does not have a way to cancel a message.

Without the ability to send a "cancel" message to your consumer, you may have to do something like what that other post suggests.

Another option to consider: message processing should be idempotent. That is, processing the same message more than once should only cause the desired result to occur once (the first time it is processed).

Idempotence is often achieved through the use of a correlationid in messaging. You can attach a correlationid to your message, then check a database or other service to see if that message should still be processed. If you want to "cancel" the message, you would update the other database/service with that specific correlationid to say "this one has been processed already" or "has been canceled" or something like that.